# Examples of two different maximal atlases given the abstract manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am very confused by the notion of the maximal atlas.

Given some separable metrizable $C^r$  manifold $\mathcal{M}$, from what I read from the internet and the book, there might be more than one maximal atlases covering it, i.e. they are not compatible with one another, and they have different $C^r$ structures.

Can anyone give me some clear explicit example(s)? (Due to the definition of maximal atlases, of course, you just need to provide non-compatible beginning atlases rather than the maximal ones).

I would really appreciate it.

---

Here's the definition of compatibility from the material I read:
Suppose we have two coordinate patches in $M$, $F_i:U_i\rightarrow V_i\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, i=1,2. The coordinate patches are $C^r$-compatible (where $r\in \mathbb{N}$ or $r=\infty$) if

1. Either $U_1\cap U_2= \emptyset$,
2. or if $U_1\cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$ but $F_{12}:=F_1\circ F_2^{-1}: F_2(U_1\cap U_2)\leftrightarrow F_1(U_1\cap U_2)$ is a bijection of $C^r(F_2(U_1\cap U_2);\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
   $F_{21}:=F_2\circ F_1^{-1}: F_1(U_1\cap U_2)\leftrightarrow F_2(U_1\cap U_2)$ is a bijection of $C^r(F_1(U_1\cap U_2);\mathbb{R}^n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the real line with a single coordinate patch given by $F_1: x\mapsto |x|^{t-1}x$ where $t$ is any real number $> 1$. You can verify that $F_1$ is a homeomorphism whose inverse is not differentiable at $0$. It is incompatible with the usual differential structure given by the coordinate $F_2: x \mapsto x$, because at the point $0$ the map $F_2 \circ F_1^{-1}$ is not differentiable. This shows that there are at least uncountably many smooth structures on the real line; you can generalise the method to generate uncountably many smooth structures from any given smooth manifold.

Comment: You can even make it slightly wilder: Choose $F_1$ such that it isn't differentiable, just continuous. Then $F_1\circ F_2^{-1}$ certainly isn't differentiable.

Comment: Almost - you would need $F_1$ to be a homeomorphism for it to qualify as a chart.

Comment: Okay... So if I am understanding this example correctly, both (particularly the first one) will lead to a $C^\infty$ atlas, because $F_1\circ F_1^{-1}=$Identity, which is of $C^\infty$, that correct?  Actually, what I am trying to ask is that do you mean "smooth" by $C^\infty$?

Comment: Yes by smooth I mean $C ^ \infty$. And yes both $(\mathbb{R},F_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R},F_2)$ are atlases for the real line.